push on-prem snmp logs to AWS S3
One of our network appliances generates SNMP logs and pushes them to a local repository on-prem.
I need the same log files to be pushed to an AWS S3 repository (managed by a 3rd-party service)
What specific information/details or parameters do I ask our 3rd-party service to provide us with access to their S3 so we can push our log?
